# Inverse Proportionality

Tags: mathematical-physics

1. Inversely proportional: $ab = K$ where $a$ and $b$ are variables and $K$ is the constant of inverse proportionality (?). So, if $a$ increases/decreases, $b$ decreases/increases. Neat!
2. $x + y = K$. $x$ and $y$ are variables and $K$ is a constant. Just like with inverse proportionality, as $x$ increases/decreases, $y$ decreases/increases. Is there a name for this addition-correlate of inverse proportionality and why doesn't it appear in *nature* at the same frequency as inverse proportionality (there's Ohm's law, there's Boyle's law, etc.).

**Addendum**

For *direct proportionality*, $\frac{a}{b} = K$, where $K$ is a constant,we can see that to keep $K$ constant, $a$ increase/decrease is accompanied by a *proportionate* increase/decrease in $b$.

This is *mirrored* perfectly (?) by $x - y = K$. If $x$ increases, $y$ too has to increase "by the same amount" and if $x$ decreases, $y$ also must decrease "by the same amount" in order that $K$ remains constant. Is this *relationship* found in *nature*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second law *does* occur often in the sciences. It occurs in the context of conservation, e.g. conserved mass/charge etc.

Think of Chemistry: if $x$ is the mass of one reactant and $y$ is the mass of the other, then $x+y$ is the total mass, a constant.